# How can you pre-load a module when invoking `cabal repl`?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Is there a way to have a module automatically load when `cabal repl` shows the ready prompt? I'd like to shortcut the following workflow with some command line options or something equivalent for `cabal repl`:

```
cabal repl
ghci> :m + Note.Query
... now I do stuff with functions in the Note.Query module
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put the command `:m + Note.Query` in a file called `.ghci`. If there is a file called `.ghci` in the current directory, then it will be run when you invoke GHCi. If there is no `.ghci` file in the current directory, but there is one in your home directory, then that will be run. This allows you to have project-specific `.ghci` files.